# How to get the last 4 digits of ssn

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Can someone, please, please help me here; I am very, very confused.

I am grabbing ssn values from an oracle database with this query:

```
SELECT
substr(SSN,6)
FROM MYTABLE
```

and I am getting the correct value of the last 4 digits

When I insert that value into a a sql server table, I am getting a different value.

For instance, let's assume that the ssn that I am grabbing is 123456789, in Oracle, I get 6789 which is correct.

However, after inserting the value into a sql server table as
`Insert into mytable (ssn) values(ssn)`, the value shows as 5678.

I also tried selecting the entire ssn as

```
SELECT
substr(SSN)
FROM MYTABLE
```

and then try inserting into a sql server db as:

```
Insert into mytable (ssn) values(right(ssn,4).
```

I still end up with 5678.

Can anyone, please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: So what are the data types of the two differnt tables for the ssn field?

Comment: Right, and what is the `INSERT ... SELECT` query, because it isn't `INSERT ... VALUES`. If you are right that you are only pulling `6789` from Oracle in the first place, then it is impossible for SQL Server to have `5678`... if you have the whole number, then it is possible that your SQL Server temporary table (I assume you're storing intermediate results somewhere) has `SSN` defined as `VARCHAR(8)`...

Comment: both are varchar(9). Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: Then you'll need to show the actual statements you're using, along with some sample data and the table declarations. SQL Server isn't doing this to you because it doesn't work; there is something in your declarations or your data that are shifting the substring over.

Comment: Oh gosh, I ams so freaking dumb. I had saved the original copy of the code into .txt file and sent to my boss, who actually discovered the problem. All this time, I had been wasting time modifying the .txt file instead of the actual code. Sorry guys; I am truly sorry for wasting your time. the .txt file had it as substr(5,4). I have now changed it to substr(6,4) and all is well. again, sorry.

Comment: yah. don't omit the third argument of substr!  Especially when peoples' identities are at stake.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the right thing...

```
SELECT RIGHT('123456789',4)
```

Or you can check length of the field that you're using

Answer (score 0):

you can get the last four digit of a number in oracle by using simple substr function.

```
select SUBSTR(ssn,(length(ssn)-4),5) from MYTABLE;
```

Comment: This should be:
select SUBSTR(ssn,(length(ssn)-3),4) from MYTABLE;